# finding, and then efficiently replacing with the reverse in java

Tags: java, regex, performance

I'm working in Java with a very large .txt file database of proteins. The proteins have a general structure, but not one that is uniform enough to hard-code a "take this from startIndex to endIndex, reverse, and replace". The only true uniformity is that they are delimited by `>`, e.g.:

`...WERINWETI>gi|230498 [Bovine Albumin]ADFIJWOENAONFOAIDNFKLSADNFATHISDATFDAIFJ>sp|234235 (human) AGP1 QWIQWONOQWNROIWQRNOQWIRNSWELLE>gi|...` and so on.

As you can see, although the actual protein sequence (the long chains of all capitals) are uniform in that they are chains of capitals, but besides that, the preceding description can be pretty much anything (there is a lot of times not a space between the description and sequence). What my program needs to do is copy the original text over to a new file, then go through, add a `r-` after each `>` (e.g. `...EERFDS>r-gi|23423...`) as well as reverse ONLY the chain of capitals. After that process is complete, I need to append it to the end of the original text.

I have completed the `r-` function, and actually I have completed the reversal and appending as well, but it is not efficient enough. The databases that are receiving this treatment are MASSIVE, and my program takes too long. In fact I have no idea how long it takes, because I never let it finish. I waited 1 hour and ended it. Here is my algorithm for the reversal using a regex (the built-in Pattern class) (the part that is computationally intensive):

```
Pattern regexSplit = Pattern.compile(">");
String[] splits = regexSplit.split(rDash.toString());
StringBuilder rDashEdited = new StringBuilder();
Pattern regexProtein = Pattern.compile("[A-Z]{5,}");

for (int splitIndex = 1; splitIndex < splits.length; splitIndex++) {
    Matcher rDashMatcher = regexProtein.matcher(splits[splitIndex]);
    rDashMatcher.find();
    StringBuffer reverser = new StringBuffer(rDashMatcher.group());
    rDashEdited.append(rDashMatcher.replaceAll(reverser.reverse().toString()) + ">");
}
System.out.println(">" + rDashEdited);
```

So, basically I split `rDash` (which is a StringBuilder that contains all the original proteins with `>r-` put in, but hasn't gone through reversal yet) into each individual protein and add them to a String array. Then I go through each string in the array and look for chains of capital letters longer than 5 letters, add the match to a StringBuffer, reverse it, and replace the forward version with the reverse. Note that this algorithm works as intended for smaller text files.

Is there a more powerful regex that would eliminate the need of splitting/traversing the array? When I tried, the `replaceAll()` call replaced ALL the downstream proteins with the reverse of the FIRST protein in the set. I checked, for fun, with `System.out.println(rDashMatcher.groupCount())` and it printed a `0` for each of the proteins in the set. Can anyone help me with a more efficient/powerful regex? It is a fairly new concept for me, but it reminds me of vectorizing in MATLAB (only with letters).

Comment: So all this data comes in as a single line from the original file, or is it one protein per line?

Comment: The line can break anywhere I'm pretty sure. Its all just a big blob on notepad. It may all be a single line and notepad just forces it to wrap at some point, but either the line breaks wherever it wants or its all one line, there can be multiple proteins per line.

Comment: Are you streaming the file or loading the whole file in memory? If you are putting it all in memory, it will be slow due to memory swaps. You are probably better off streaming data from the file, store upto a ">", and do the second part of your program on the stored data.

Comment: Oh, I see. So instead of keeping that whole String array choking up my memory, just read it line by line. That makes way more sense, thanks, Ill try it.

Comment: If the whole thing is one line, you can't read it line by line, but you can read it "block by block". Let my try to give a skeleton implementation

Comment: The reason `groupCount()` returns zero is because there are no capturing groups in your regex.  It has nothing to do with what got matched or even if there *was* a match.  It's a static property of the associated Pattern object,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I threw 10,000,000 records (came to ~379MB text files) at this and it took 1:06 minutes.(4core athlon, a few years old)

The big if tree handles the ends where you only get half because the delimiter is in the middle of an element.

```
public void readProteins(BufferedReader br, BufferedWriter bw) throws IOException
{     
  Pattern regexSplit = Pattern.compile(">");
  Pattern proteinPattern = Pattern.compile("(.*?)([A-Z]{5,})");
  Matcher m;
  Scanner s = new Scanner(br);
  s.useDelimiter(regexSplit);         
  while (s.hasNext())
  {
      StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
      String protein = s.next();
      m = proteinPattern.matcher(protein);            
      if (m.find())
          sb.append(m.group(2)).reverse().append(">r-").insert(0, m.group(1));
      else
          sb.append(protein);
      );          
  }
  bw.flush();
  bw.close();
}
```

Comment: `m.groupCount()` is always going to be `2`, because that's how many capturing groups there are in your regex.  It has nothing to do with what was actually matched.

Comment: So it is.  Fixed.  Think I screwed myself up having m.find() in the debugger at one point.

Comment: As it turns out, it is possible that the protein breaks mid-line in some of the databases I'll be working with, meaning there may be a LF character somewhere in the line. Is there a way to modify the regex to account for this, and take the WHOLE sequence rather than just the line? I tried adding the \n into the regex, but of course, that didn't work (realized how dumb that was after the fact). Sorry for digging this back up.

Answer (score 1):

Some ideas for optimization:

- Avoid StringBuffer. StringBuilder provides same functionality and
  is faster.
- Rather than replaceAll you can use
  stringBuilder.replace(int start, int end, String str), that will
  avoid trying to match pattern in whole string again.
- With approach #b you can even skip splitting keep searching for protiens
  and replacing them as it comes.

It is always best to run with profiler and see what is consuming time rather than guessing. For instance it may be possible to improve the performance by increase memory of your program or avoiding certain slow file system etc.

Comment: Is there a way to set the memory allotted to the program? If so, how? I would like that to be pretty much the only thing going on. I will also keep in mind that StringBuilder is more efficient, I didn't know that. The reason I could't do the StringBuilder.replace is because they all returned as the same group--so it gave an error for the start and end indexes. Could you provide an example perhaps of how you coudl use the StringBuilder replace with a regex?

Comment: The memory alloted to the program can be set by using -Xmx switch. While running the program, you should use `java -Xmx2G <classname>` to use 2GB.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a more powerful regex, you just need to streamline your process so you don't keep handling the same bits of text over and over. For the most part, that means using Java's lower-level regex API, namely `appendReplacement()` and `appendTail()`.  And by passing an empty string to `appendReplacement()` I avoided its automatic processing of backreferences.

Notice how I used `find()`, too.  If you ever find yourself calling `find()` (or `matches()` or `lookingAt()`) and *not* checking its return value, you're doing something wrong.  That's how you know if the match succeeded.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
  // this I/O code is bare-bones so as not to distract from the fun stuff
  BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("test_out.txt"));

  // I use a lookahead so the ">" doesn't get discarded
  Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("test.txt")).useDelimiter("(?=>)");
  while (sc.hasNext())
  {
    bw.write(reverseCapBlocks(sc.next()));
  }
  sc.close();
  bw.close();
}

// cache these because recompiling them is fairly expensive
static final Pattern CAPS_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("\\b[A-Z]{5,}\\b");
static final Pattern BRACKET_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("^>");

static String reverseCapBlocks(String s)
{
  StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
  Matcher m = CAPS_PATTERN.matcher(s);
  while (m.find())
  {
    // appends whatever was between the last match and this one
    // but hole off on appending the current match
    m.appendReplacement(sb, "");
    String temp = m.group();

    // do the reversing manually because it's trivial and it avoids
    // creating a new StringBuilder every time
    for (int i = temp.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
      sb.append(temp.charAt(i));
    }
  }
  // append whatever was left after the last match
  m.appendTail(sb);

  // if the chunk began with ">", add the "r-"
  return BRACKET_PATTERN.matcher(sb).replaceFirst(">r-");
}
```

I use StringBuffer instead of StringBuilder because that's what the API requires, but it's not a big deal; reports of StringBuffer's inefficiency, while true, tend to be highly exaggerated.

Comment: All of this has been extremely helpful. Thank you

Comment: As it turns out, it is possible that the protein breaks mid-line in some of the databases I'll be working with, meaning there may be a LF character somewhere in the line. Is there a way to modify the regex to account for this, and take the WHOLE sequence rather than just the line? I tried adding the \n into the regex, but of course, that didn't work (realized how dumb that was after the fact). Sorry for digging this back up.

Comment: I got it, all I had to do was change the structure of the while and for loop around slightly. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: That's a relief!  I couldn't see how line separators could cause problems, given that I never used the dot (`.`) metacharacter.  Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in my comment, you should not load the whole file in memory. This will cause memory to swap in and out and make your program slow.

If the size of the "protein" i.e. `>` delimited strings are manageable in memory, this should do the trick

```
    Scanner scanner = null;
    BufferedWriter writer = null;
    try {
        writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("output.txt"));
        scanner  = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader("input.txt")));
        scanner.useDelimiter(">");
        while ( scanner.hasNext() ) {
           doReverseAndWriteToFile(scanner.next(), writer);
        }
    } finally {
        if ( scanner != null) {
            scanner.close();
        }
        if ( writer != null ) {
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
        }
    }
```

in `doReverseAndWriteToFile()` you should put the second part of your program ( which I didn't pay much attention to :-) ). In this function, you should also write to the new file, as you go along.

If you use this, you only have the "bufferSize" + "length of one protein" in memory at one time.

See if this speeds it up.. otherwise you have to look elsewhere.